# WPF Combobox is blank (data binding)

Tags: wpf

I followed a simple tutorial for comboboxes (http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/combobox-control/).
Here is my XAML for the combobox :

```
<ComboBox Name="CoursesTeach" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1"  Width="150" Height="Auto" Margin="0,24">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Black" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
```

Code behind :

```
public AddTrainer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            using (Model1Container context = new Model1Container())
            {

                foreach (var row in context.CourseSet)
                {
                    if (row.Discipline != null)
                    {                     
                        CoursesTeach.ItemsSource = row.Discipline;                       
                    }
                    MetroCustomBox.ShowOK(row.Discipline); // i can see right values    

                }

            }
        }
```

But the results are just NOT in the combobox, although I can perfectly can print them.
Thanks a lot for your responses.

Comment: What is `Discipline`?

Answer (score 0):

To add items in your Combobox by code behind you may use Items property.
With your previous code :

```
foreach (var row in context.CourseSet)
{
     if (row.Discipline != null)
     {                     
         CoursesTeach.Items.Add(row.Discipline);                       
     }  
 }
```

But a better way, is use ItemsSource property, with binding, or set by a List.
With your previous code :

```
CoursesTeach.ItemsSource = context.CourseSet.Where(row => row.Dicipline != null).Select(row => row.Dicipline).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my combobox still appears white like this : http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/813704Sanstitre.png . I have indeed 5 row in my database, but the text won't appear.

Comment: Do you have a binding Error on your output window?

Comment: Allright, i'm definitely lame. It was simply Text="{Bindind}" instead of Text="{Bindind Name}". Thanks for the patience.